# smartgwt - DynamicForm relative column width

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

If i create a DynamicForm as shown below the FormItems of the DynamicForm are placed over 2 rows. I expected them to be in one row. The place should be distributed as folowing: 20 px for the first column, 250 for the second and the rest for the third.

```
final DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
FormItem[] fi = new FormItem[3];
// filling the list with one CheckboxItem, one TextItem and one SelectItem
df.setColWidths("20", "250", "*");
df.setNumCols(3);
df.setFields(fi);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result screenshot]

I wanted to have all FormItems in one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically title of form item also takes one column. If you do want to show the title also then it will double the column count.

For more info have a look at [DynamicForm#setColWidths()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/DynamicForm.html#setColWidths%28java.lang.Object...%29).

---

As per you comment:

```
//filling the list with one CheckboxItem, one TextItem and one SelectItem?
```

Try this one:

```
    final DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
    // FormItem[] fi = new FormItem[3];
    // filling the list with one CheckboxItem, one TextItem and one SelectItem

    CheckboxItem ci = new CheckboxItem();
    ci.setShowTitle(false);
    ci.setTitle("");

    TextItem ti = new TextItem();
    ti.setShowTitle(false);

    SelectItem si = new SelectItem();
    si.setShowTitle(false);
    si.setValues("PDF");

    df.setItems(ci, ti, si);

    df.setColWidths("20", "250", "*");
    df.setNumCols(3);
    // df.setFields(fi);

    RootPanel.get().add(df);
```

Snapshot:

[image]

---

As per your snapshot:

Try this one

```
    final DynamicForm df = new DynamicForm();
    // FormItem[] fi = new FormItem[3];

    CheckboxItem ci = new CheckboxItem();
    ci.setShowTitle(false);
    ci.setTitle("");

    SelectItem si = new SelectItem();
    si.setTitle("LANGUAGE");
    si.setValues("PDF");

    df.setItems(ci, si);

    df.setColWidths("20", "250", "*");
    df.setNumCols(3);
    // df.setFields(fi);

    RootPanel.get().add(df);
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Try both options as per your requirement.